# HTML/CSS/PHP - multiple quotation marks

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, quotes

We all know that a quotation mark must have it's partner. But how will I do it if I got 3 consecutive elements that wil use up a quotation mark (PHP echo, HTML and CSS class, Javascript function)? Something like this

```
echo '
    <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu('edit-user-window')">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>
';
```

The echo's quotation mark breaks at the start of my onclick function. How do I do it?

Comment: Use backward slash before the quotation mark...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply escape it:

```
echo ' <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu(\'edit-user-window\')">.....';
```

---

**Notes**

The error you are receiving comes because you effectively "break" the string at those points. It is bad concatenation. And by using the `\` before those commas (`'`), you're telling the php interpreter to **ignore** the character that follows that slash (`\`) which, in this case is the comma (`'`).

Comment: The first solution would not work as the OP is also using speech marks in the string.

Comment: @swiss196 Good spot, Didn't see that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Skip it using the slash

```
echo '
    <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu(\'edit-user-window\')">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \ to escape a character, so your example would look like:

```
echo '
    <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu(\'edit-user-window\')">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash like this...

```
onclick="showMenu(\'edit-user-window\')"
```

Backslashes are used in PHP to escape special characters within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use either a backward slash `\` before `'` -> `\'` (also works if you work with strings encapsulated in `"` -> `\"`)

```
echo '
    <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu(\'edit-user-window\')">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>
';
```

or use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

```
echo <<<EOT
    <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu('edit-user-window')">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using single quotes use only double qoutes in it or vice versa
as

```
echo '
 <tr class="table-body" onclick="showMenu("edit-user-window")">
        <td> <input type="submit" class="delete-but graphic-buts" value="" /> </td>
        <td> <a href="/res/doc.docx" target="_blank"> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>

'
```

or

```
echo "
 <tr class='table-body' onclick='showMenu('edit-user-window')'>
        <td> <input type='submit' class='delete-but graphic-buts' value='' /> </td>
        <td> <a href='/res/doc.docx' target='_blank'> User </a> </td>
        <td> Pass </td>
        <td> user </td>
        <td> View-Only </td>
    </tr>

"
```